# Dataframe, keep only one column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I can't find the pandas function that returns a one column `Dataframe` from a multi column `DF`.
I need the exact opposit function of the `drop([''])` one.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can just do `df = df['col']` if you want a single column

Comment: `df = df['column'].to_frame()`

Comment: or df = df[['col']]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the following notation to return a single column dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(1, 100 ,(10, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))

df_out = df[['C']]
```

Output:

```
    C
0  65
1  48
2   1
3  41
4  85
5  55
6  45
7  10
8  44
9  11
```

Note: df['C'] returns a series. And, you can use the `to_frame` method to convert that series into a dataframe. Or use the double brackets, [[]].

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I would like to show how we can use the parameter `drop` to obtain a one column dataframe from a multicolumn one. Also, I explain the result using the `tidyverse` universe [(paper)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyverse/vignettes/paper.html).

Working with a minimal example for a dataframe DF

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = c("e", "f"))
str(DF)
#> 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ a: int  1 2
#>  $ b: chr  "e" "f"
```

By the way, note that in R versions lower than 4.0, column b would be a factor by default (unless we use `stringsAsFactors= FALSE`)

Operator `[` returns a list (dataframe) as it preserves the original structure (dataframe)

```r
DF[1]
#>   a
#> 1 1
#> 2 2

DF['a']
#>   a
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
```

On the other hand, operator `[[` simplifies the result to the simplest structure possible, a vector for a one-column dataframe. In the three expressions of it, you always get the simplified version (a vector)

```r
DF[[1]]
#> [1] 1 2

DF[['a']]
#> [1] 1 2

DF$a
#> [1] 1 2
```

Finally, using `[` with row and column dimension

```r
DF[, 1]
#> [1] 1 2
```

also returns the simplified version because the parameter `drop` is set to TRUE by default. Setting it to FALSE, you preserve the structure and obtain a one-column dataframe

```r
DF[, 1, drop = FALSE]
#>   a
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
```

A good explanation of this point can be found at: Advanced R by Hadley Wickham, CRC, 2015, section 3.2.1 or section 4.2.5 in the on-line version of the [book](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html?q=drop#simplify-preserve) (June 2021)

Finally, within the `tidyverse` universe [CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tidyverse), you always obtain a dataframe (tibble) when selecting one column

```r
DF %>% 
  select(2)
#>   b
#> 1 e
#> 2 f

DF %>% 
  select("a")
#>   a
#> 1 1
#> 2 2

DF %>% 
  select(a)
#>   a
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple just use the double brace to select it.
It will return the result in Data Frame. You can check it by `type(df)`

```
# First create a data frame to check this
column = df[['Risk']]
print(column)
print(type(column))
```